# Why is Mongo 2.6.5 continuously logging about SyncSourceFeedback

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I'm running a 3 node replica set with Mongo 2.6.5, where `db1` is the primary, and `db2` and `db3` are the secondaries.

`db2`, one of the secondaries, continuously (once or twice a second) logs this line:

```
2015-12-15T21:06:09.852+0000 [SyncSourceFeedbackThread] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to db1.example.com:27017
2015-12-15T21:06:10.363+0000 [SyncSourceFeedbackThread] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to db1.example.com:27017
2015-12-15T21:06:10.877+0000 [SyncSourceFeedbackThread] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to db1.example.com:27017
2015-12-15T21:06:11.404+0000 [SyncSourceFeedbackThread] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to db1.example.com:27017
2015-12-15T21:06:11.917+0000 [SyncSourceFeedbackThread] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to db1.example.com:27017
2015-12-15T21:06:12.445+0000 [SyncSourceFeedbackThread] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to db1.example.com:27017
2015-12-15T21:06:12.956+0000 [SyncSourceFeedbackThread] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to db1.example.com:27017
```

`rs.status()` returns this:

```
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-12-15T21:01:16Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "db1.example.com:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 33612785,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1450213276, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-12-15T21:01:16Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1443584172, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-09-30T03:36:12Z"),
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "db2.example.com:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 6513888,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1450213275, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-12-15T21:01:15Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-12-15T21:01:15Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-12-15T21:01:16Z"),
            "pingMs" : 1,
            "syncingTo" : "db1.example.com:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "name" : "db3.example.com:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 6629116,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1450213273, 4),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-12-15T21:01:13Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-12-15T21:01:14Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-12-15T21:01:16Z"),
            "pingMs" : 0,
            "syncingTo" : "db1.example.com:27017"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

What could the issue be?